# Which Beis Hamikdash are we mourning?

Tags: fast-days, beis-hamikdash

As mentioned in another question, we have a few fast days, mostly connected to the destruction of the Beis Hamikdash. Yet, which one?

1. Tzom Gedalya, 10th of Teves are exclusively 1st Beis Hamikdash related
2. 17th of Tammuz, [according to the Bavli Taanis 28b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=28b&format=text) was exclusively 2nd Beis Hamikdash (and we *don't* fast on the 9th which was when the walls of Jerusalem were broken)
3. Tisha Be'Av - Both.

Why can't we be consistent? Either fast on the 9th, or replace Tzom Gedalya and 10th of Teves with parallel 2nd Beis Hamikdash events?

Comment: I don't understand. Why not mourn both?

Comment: @msh210 but we don't do that either. We don't fast on the 9th

Comment: @msh210 See Aruch Hashulchan [549:4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%98). However, it still doesn't answer why we don't fast on the day when the Romans besieged Jerusalem.

Comment: Your question is why we mourn both, not one. My comment asked *why* we should mourn one, not both. Mourning both seems reasonable to me. I'm not sure what you're trying to prove from the _AHS_: afaict he says we mourn both ("ואף על גב דבבית ראשון הובקעה ירושלים בתשעה בתמוז...  מכל מקום לא תקנו בו התענית רק בשבעה עשר שבשנייה בו הובקעה העיר ואצלינו חמיר לן חורבן בית שני"), but I never doubted that, and your questions is assuming as a premise that we mourn both. Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @msh210 My question is that it seems that we're partly mourning over one and partly mourning over the other. We're not being consistent. If we'd mourn over both (even minus the 9th of Tammuz) it would be consistent.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that I don't see the difference between what you're referring to as "partly mourning over one and partly mourning over the other" and what you're referring to as "mourn[ing] over both". Afaict we do mourn both.

Comment: The answer to the part of your question is that there was no parallel event to Tzom Gedalya in the 2nd Beis Hamikdash.

Comment: @Ypnypn 10th of Teves?

Comment: @msh210 why don't we fast over the siege of Jerusalem by the Romans?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, *instead* of 10 _Teves_? or in addition? If you mean to ask the latter, then ask it in the question: that's not how your question currently reads. And if you mean to ask that that should *replace* 10 _Teves_, then, again, I don't see why you want to mourn only one _bayis_, not both.

Comment: The first mikdash was destroyed on the 5th or 10th of Av. The point is to have a fast in each of the listed months. So in Tammuz/4thmonth we switched the day to something more relevant. Some opinions held that the fast of Tevet/10thmonth is on 5 Tevet because of some other bad events.